# should Composition.author have Patient as possible value

Tags: hl7-fhir

Composition.author has two possible values Resource(Practitioner|Device). What if this composition is created by patient, should composition allow Patient as possible author? I am thinking about case where patient will like to report his blood pressure on a daily basis to FHIR server..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks. Actually, this is something I am supposed to have done already. I'll make the change shortly